# What is the new method for TYPO3 pi_getFFvalue

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, pibase

im refactoring a decent sized TYPO3 project and have to refactor the part with the methods

```
$eIds = $this->pi_getFFvalue($this->cObj->data['pi_flexform'], 'selected_contacts', 'sDEF');
```

what is the new approach for extbase to fetch values from a flexform? having a really hard time finding the correct solution.

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the XML-Tags to settings.name inside your flexforms and use:

```
$this->settings['name']
```

Check this for an example: [enter link description here](http://www.pi-phi.de/171.html)